# Sumproduct for conditional sum based on rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have table formatted as show below:

[image: Data table]

I'd like to write `conditional sum` formula in cell F15 to calculate sum based `Year, Country, Product` together.

I try to use `sumproduct` to complete this task, but I was only able to calculate sum based on 2 variables: `Year` and `Country`.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A11=C15)*(C1:Z1=E15);C3:Z11)`

Is there a way how to add 3rd variable into this `sumproduct` formula? Or is there another way to complete this task (I can't change formating of the table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have a problem when I tried it - as long as the first part of the SUMPRODUCT works out to an array with the same dimensions as the second part, it should be OK.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A11=C15)*(B3:B11=D15)*(C1:Z1=E15);C3:Z11)
```